# how to change object value in react hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a state with object {mode: 'light'} when the handleChange I click setMode to {mode: 'dark'} when the handleChange is clicked again it should return to {mode: 'light'} the flow is the same as toggling the hooks but Using an object, I tried it several times but it didn't work, how do I do it right?

this my state mode

```
 const [mode, setMode] = useState({
    mode: 'LIGHT'
  })
```

this my event

```
const handleChangeTheme = (e) => {
    setMode({
      ...mode,
      mode: 'DARK'
    })
  }
```

I throw the state to another component to display the state

```
<Navbar handleChangeTheme={handleChangeTheme} mode={mode.mode} />
```

this component navbar

```
 <li onClick={handleChangeTheme}>
    <span className='nav-item nav-link'>
        <b>{checked}</b>
     </span>
  </li>
```

when the handleChange is clicked it should look like true or false but this is an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like below. State change will reflect when object is assigned as new

```
const handleChangeTheme = (e) => {
  let newMode = Object.assign({}, mode);
  newMode.mode = mode.mode === "LIGHT" ? "DARK" : "LIGHT";
  setMode(newMode);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually toggle the mode, try [using functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates):

```
const toggleMode = () =>
  setMode((prev) => ({ ...prev, mode: !prev.mode }));

<li onClick={toggleMode}>...</li>;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change state as `boolean` it will simplify.

```
const [mode, setMode] = useState(true);

<Navbar
  handleChangeTheme={() => setMode(!mode)}
  mode={mode ? "LIGHT" : "DARK"}
/>;
```